# using pandas to find not null cells inside csv file and print them into a new one

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a csv file with 3 columns inside as in the picture

[image]

I want to get the English and Spanish but ignore the fields that are null in Spanish so my expected output is

[image]

any Ideas how to do it ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to read the file using pandas but it prints all the files i want it to ignore the nulls and just print the English and Spanish

Comment: So you want to drop the rows where Spanish is null? Have a look here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: Use `df = df.dropna(subset=['English','Spanish'])`

Comment: @jezrael but it prints the French as well is there a solution for that ? can you post it as an answer please so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with `subset` for list for test missing values and then remove `French` column by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['English','Spanish']).drop(['French'],axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or if only 3 columns first remove `French` and then test all columns:

```
df1 = df.drop(['French'], axis=1).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: df1 = tdata.dropna(subset=['English','Spanish']).dropna('French', axis=1)
TypeError: dropna() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Comment: what does that mean ?

Comment: @programmingfreak - oops, my typo, it is `drop`

Comment: thank you so much man I will use .reset_index(drop=True) to reset the indexs as well

Comment: @Jezeal what if I have one more column to drop like dutch ? when I place it next to french it tells TypeError: drop() got multiple values for argument 'axis'
is there a solution around it ?

Comment: `['French', 'Dutch']`